# Map all characters except ones inside curly braces

Tags: php, regex

I have two arrays for transliteration,

```
$latin = ['dž', 'lj', 'nj',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'č', 'ć',
    'd', 'đ', 'e', 'f', 'g',
    'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 
    's', 'š', 't', 'u', 'v', 
    'z', 'ž',
    'DŽ', 'LJ', 'NJ', 'Dž', 'Lj', 'Nj',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'Č', 'Ć',
    'D', 'Đ', 'E', 'F', 'G',
    'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
    'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 
    'S', 'Š', 'T', 'U', 'V', 
    'Z', 'Ž'
];

$cyrillic = ['џ', 'љ', 'њ',
    'a', 'б', 'ц', 'ч', 'ћ',
    'д', 'ђ', 'e', 'ф', 'г',
    'x', 'и', 'j', 'к', 'л',
    'm', 'н', 'o', 'п', 'p', 
    'c', 'ш', 'т', 'y', 'b', 
    'з', 'ж',
    'Џ', 'Љ', 'Њ', 'Џ', 'Љ', 'Њ',
    'A', 'Б', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ћ',
    'Д', 'Ђ', 'E', 'Ф', 'Г',
    'X', 'И', 'J', 'K', 'Л',
    'M', 'H', 'O', 'П', 'P', 
    'C', 'Ш', 'T', 'Y', 'B', 
    'З', 'Ж'
];
```

so when I use `str_replace($latin, $cyrillic, $string)`, it works great.

But `string` could be something like this:

```
$string = 'Today is {day_name} and time is {time}';
```

Is it possible to map all characters except the ones inside curly braces.

This is example:

```
$string = 'Today is {day_name} and time is {time}';
echo str_replace($latin, $cyrillic, $string);
```

Comment: Show your code that you have tried please

Comment: Serbian transliteration - nice! I have written my converter from Cyrillic to Latin that works well, but from Latin to Cyrillic there are challenges like proper names that should stay in the original.

Comment: @bub I've added code in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the string by the `{}` enclosed chars using the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tV8sY2/2) -

```
(\{[^}]*\})
```

and then selectively apply the string replace logic.
Something like this -

```
$string = "sad {day_name} and time is {time}";

// Split by the regex
$s_arr =preg_split(
    "/({[^}]*})/",
    $string,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);

// The string is split such that only odd numbers 
// constitute the split value
foreach($s_arr as $k=>&$m){
    if($k%2 === 0){
        $m = str_replace($latin, $cyrillic, $m);
    }
}
unset($m);

$resp_str = implode("", $s_arr);
echo $resp_str;
```

OUTPUT -

```
caÐ´ {day_name} aÐ½Ð´ Ñ‚Ð¸me Ð¸c {time}
```

Comment: Note that negated character class `[^}]*` is more efficient than lazy dot matching. You do not need to escape `}` in PHP regex either.

Comment: @stribizhev awesome... Brought down the number of steps from 24 to 12 after using negated char class... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$arr = array_combine($latin, $cyrillic);
$string = 'Today is {day_name} and time is {time}';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|./', function ($m) use ($arr) {
  return array_key_exists($m[0], $arr) ? $arr[$m[0]] : $m[0];
},
$string);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FH60i2), result: `Toдay иc {day_name} aнд тиme иc {time}`.

Here, I combine the two arrays into 1 array with keys and values, then match any character but a newline (=key) (add `/s` modifier to match all) and check if the key exists in the array. If yes, replace.

The regex matches:

- `\{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)` - a substring starting with `{` followed by 0 or more characters other than `}` and then matching a closing `}` and the whole matched substring is omitted from the match value due to the verbs `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`
- `|` - or...
- `.` - any character but a newline.

See [the regex demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kG6hQ5/1).

Comment: @stribizhev, I have one question... `\{[^}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)` why there is a backslash in the beginning of pattern?

Comment: In order to make sure the `{` is treated as a literal opening brace. Although PHP regex engine is smart and can understand that if there is no digit after the brace it is not a limiting quantifier (like `{1,4}`), still, it is best practice to introduce as little ambiguity to regex as possible.